# Can not boot into NUC5CPYH (Celeron 3050) with ubuntu 14.04 (Kernel 3.19)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, login, intel-nuc

I am trying to make a TV tuner work and the instructions mentioned to compile custom kernel 3.19 with the provided patch. I have done the same and the system now recognizes the device perfectly as analog tv tuner.

The problem is I can not use the graphical UI to login to the system. I am stuck in infininte login loop. I have been through many post updated desktop. Currently I am using terminal to login. It seems to be a **intel graphics driver issue**.

I have tried use the device with patched and compiled kernel using source of 4.5.1 but although it lets me login and do other things. The devices does not get recognized as analog tv tuner.

**Is it possible to sort this issue out? I haven't tried any other version of kernel 3.x? Anyone having successful login using kernel 3.x on latest Intel NUC5CPYH?**